# Countif with literal array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

Why does this formula not work: `COUNTIF({1,2,3},2)`?

I can use both `COUNT()` and `COUNTIF()` with a range, but I can replace the range with a literal array only on `COUNT`, not on `COUNTIF`.

If I use `LET` to first assign the array to a name, then I can use a literal array in `COUNTIF`, but i get the wrong result.

This is the content of a little test that I am using:

|  | A | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 |  |
| **2** | 2 |  |
| **3** | 3 |  |
| **4** |  |  |
| **5** | =COUNT(A1:A3) |  |
| **6** | =COUNTIF(A1:A3,2) |  |
| **7** | =COUNT({1,2,3}) |  |
| **8** | =COUNTIF({1,2,3},2) | Excel doesn't allow to enter this formula |
| **9** |  |  |
| **10** | =LET(a,A1:A3,COUNT(a)) |  |
| **11** | =LET(a,A1:A3,COUNTIF(a,2)) |  |
| **12** | =LET(a,{1,2,3},COUNT(a)) |  |
| **13** | =LET(a,{1,2,3},COUNTIF(a,2)) | Excel allows this, but the result is wrong |

The following snapshot shows the formulas I'm trying to use:

> [image]

The following snapshot shows the results:

> [image]

The following snapshot shows the error message when I try to enter the formula in A8:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use arrays in place of ranges with any of the `*IF(S)` formulas.  They require ranges.

One can use SUMPRODUCT to do most:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--({1,2,3}=2))
```

This will return an array: `{0,1,0}` to the SUMPRODUCT which will then sum them and return `1`

Comment: Thanks... Do you know if this is documented and what is the reason? Or this limitation exists just because?

Comment: I am not sure if it is documented, but the documentation only refers to ranges.  As to why....I have now idea.